# Check whether a directory exists in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I know, *I know*, this sounds *soo* easy. But I can't seem to find the correct answer on the Internet.

One of the solution I found was to use `is_dir`.

```
if(is_dir($dir))
  echo 'directory exists';
else
  echo 'drectory not exist';
```

But this is ***wrong***-- All this function does is to check whether the `$dir` is a directory, it doesn't check whether the directory exists, or not. In other words if I put:

```
$rootDir = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\test\\My Documents\\Image Directory\\Me Dog\\";
```

then the function will return a true, even though you can find no such directory on your web server.

Any ideas?

Comment: This was a reported bug in php 5.2, though I can no longer find the link to the bug report.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Should work correctly. From `is_dir()` documentation:

> Returns TRUE if the filename **exists
>   and is a directory**, FALSE 
>   otherwise.

Well, anyway if it doesn't try this:

```
if(file_exists($dir) && is_dir($dir))
```

BTW. results of these functions are cached in stat cache. Use [clearstatcache()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) to clean that cache.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to use [opendir()](http://www.php.net/function.opendir) after is_dir() agrees that the path (could) be a directory.

If the resource returned by opendir() is valid, you know you have a directory, and already have a handle to read it.

Just be sure to call closedir(), either way, if a valid handle is returned.

Edit:

This answer assumes that you'll be opening the directory either way. If you just need to ensure a path is sane / valid, file_exists() is much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool file_exists ( string $filename )
```

Checks whether a file or directory exists.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if(is_dir($dir) && is_writeable($dir))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: not a solution to the problem, because non-writeable directories are directories too.