# How to check if scandir() returns any error or warning?

Tags: php, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check whether a Directory Exists in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746672/check-whether-a-directory-exists-in-php)

I am trying scandir() to check contents of directories and sending path parameter using javascript and trying to load the contents in #container div:

```
$("#container").load("fetch_images.php?path="+pathvariable);
```

in fetch_images.php I am trying `scandir($_GET['pathvariable'])` to scan the elements of given directory. My problem is if proper path is not supplied using $_GET['pathvariable'] the page is showing some warning and error.

trying to scan like `$files_dir_results = scandir($path);` and using `foreach()` to display all results of the array.

I don't want to show any kind of warning or error on output page. I know I can disable PHP warning but I will prefer any better option.

I don't know how to check if scandir() is returing any error or warning. thanks.

Comment: According to [PHP's docs](http://php.net/scandir) scandir "returns an array of filenames on success, or FALSE on failure. If directory is not a directory, then boolean FALSE is returned, and an error of level E_WARNING is generated."

Comment: Thanks noko, I just wanted not to generate E_warning, so I think its better to check if the argument supplied is directory or not then proceed with scandir as the two answers suggested.

Comment: http://php.net/is_dir - your question is more or less a request to search the manual for you. See as well: [Check whether a Directory Exists in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/746672/367456)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first check if the path is valid with [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) then scan it

```
$images = array();
$valid_images = array('jpg','png','gif');
if(is_dir($_GET['path'])){
  foreach(scandir($_GET['path']) as $file){
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_images)){
      array_push($images, $file);
    }   
 }
}

echo json_encode($images);
```

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to first check if directory is existing with `is_dir()`. Then, if directory exists, do `scandir()`