# IF statement not working in self-referencing form

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an if statement in PHP to create a directory to upload files into. I'm using a form that references itself, so that I can create another folder and upload another set of files to a different folder with a different name, or another set of files to the same folder if I so choose, once the first has completed. The problem is that the `if` statement I'm using doesn't seem to work. When I submit the form, it created the folder a second time whether the folder already exists or not.

What is going on with my `if` statement?

```
<?php
    $dirname = $_REQUEST['dirname'];
    $taken = $_REQUEST['taken'];
    $location = $_REQUEST['location'];
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    $urldirectory = $_REQUEST['urldirectory'];

    function makeDirectory($dirname) {
        mkdir(trim($dirname, 0777));
        mkdir(trim($dirname.'/thumbs', 0777));
    } 

    if (file_exists($dirname)) {
        echo "the directory exists and it is called: " . trim($dirname);        
    } else {
        makeDirectory($dirname);
    }

    //........... code omitted from here for brevity............

?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload2.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746672/check-whether-a-directory-exists-in-php).

Comment: well you cannot possible create 2 dirs with the same name in the same parent directory.

Comment: Where's the input field for the directory name?

Comment: I think that you are doing the check and creating of the directory irrespective of whether it is actually a POST request (which would mean the form was submitted) or just the GET request that showed the form to the user in the first place might be the problem here.

Comment: Oswald, the input field for the directory name is in another form that references this one. There's also an input field in this one, but I omitted it for length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems in the way how you handle directory creation and checking:

- You check if `$dirname` exists and if it doesn't you create `trim($dirname, 0777)`.
- `trim` expects a string as second parameter, but you pass an integer (i.e. `0777`). My guess is, you want to pass `0777` to `mkdir`, not to `trim`.

I don't know about the second point, but the first point definitely can lead to `file_exists($dirname)` failing on two consecutive form submissions with the same form values. I suggest to sanitize request values as early as possible, i.e. to use

```
$dirname = trim($_REQUEST['dirname']);
```

and use `$dirname` from there on without the need for any further trimming

Comment: It's also better to explicitly use `$_POST['dirname']` or `$_GET['dirname']` (though I would recommend against a GET request, as it changes something on the server).

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. I'd put trim() on every instance of $makedir while trying to solve another problem.